# Error dealing with Fragment List View, Cannot find symbol 'list'

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-listview

So I'm in the process of moving my code that worked in an all activities environment to one that uses one or two activities plus a bunch of fragments. What I'm having issues with is right now I'm trying to convert an activity that takes a bunch of JSON text based objects from the web, saves them to the local SQLite DB and then queries them and puts them into a ListView. It wasn't too hard to port over the JSON SQLite stuff, but I'm having issues with the list view...specifically at the findViewById line where it "Cannot find symbol 'list'"

Here is my onCreateView code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);

    dbHelper.open();
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllTestObjects();
    dbHelper.close();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            SQLiteDbAdapter.test_object_id,
    };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[]{
            R.id.test_object_id,
    };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    //as well as the layout information
    SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(), R.layout.home_test_objects_info,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            int testObjectId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SQLiteDbAdapter.test_object_id));
            DynamoDBManager.CoreInfo listCore = new DynamoDBManager.CoreInfo(testObjectId, "", "");
            // Do action based on listCore
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

For my fragment_event_list.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.EventFragment">    

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />   

</FrameLayout>
```

And for the object setup for the objects that will populate the ListView, home_events_info.xml which will have other TextView items in it at some point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/eventsRelLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_object_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The main differences between my activity code and this is that I used the Fragment (List) template and it auto-named the id for fragment_event_list.xml as list instead of listview1 which I had in my activity_home.xml and doesn't use LinearLayout but FrameLayout.

activity_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I imagine these differences account for my current issue as Fragment and FrameLayout work different than Activity and LinearLayout, but I'm not sure how/why and how to fix the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your id attribute of Listview is not properly set on the xml

Change: android:id="@android:id/list"

For: android:id="@+id/list"